# can't figure out mysql datatime

Tags: php, datetime

So I'm pulling my hair out over the most stupid of situations...  I'm trying to save a new time to a MySQL DB and have tried everything I can think of to make this work, but I can't for some reason.  Here's what I've got...

```
$_ = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s",time());
if (! mysql_query("UPDATE Accounts 
    SET likes='1',update='".$_."' 
    WHERE username='".$_POST['username']."'")) { ... }
```

I've tried:

```
update=FROM_UNIXTIME(".$_.")
update=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(".strtotime($_).")
update=UNIX_TIMESTAMP('".strtotime($_)."')
update='".UNIX_TIMESTAMP(strtotime($_))."'
update='".UNIX_TIMESTAMP($_)."'
update='".$_."'
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated!
Thanks,
Dave

Comment: And `mysql_error()` says what?

Comment: I would advise always storing unix time in a database. You can always convert from it later in your application and it removes any hassles with DST or Timezones. Also, you should not use `mysql_*` functions anymore.

Comment: fyi: your sample code is affectable by sql-injections! secure it before you use that code in production!

Comment: @thatidiotguy Always storing dates generated using `gmdate()` does something similar :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use `update` as a column name, you should escape it with backticks because it's a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). The value of `$_` is fine for the field itself.

```
mysql_query(" ... SET likes = 1, `update` = '$_' ...")
```

And another thing; you should escape the value of `$_POST['username']` to avoid SQL injection:

```
" ... WHERE username='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) . "'");
```

You can also combine everything using a format string, like:

```
$sql = sprintf("UPDATE Accounts SET likes='%d',`update`=%s' WHERE username='%s'", 
    1,
    $_,
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])
);

$res = mysql_query($sql) or die("yikes: " . mysql_error());
```

Also:

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE Accounts SET likes='1',update='".$_."' WHERE username='".$_POST['username']."'")
```

You have two options, the `now()`, or `curdate()` functions within your query.

The `now()` returns the date, aswell as a time stamp in the format; `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

The `curdate()` returns the date in the format YYYY-MM-DD

Your query will look like:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE Accounts SET likes='1', `update`='now()' WHERE username='".$_POST['username']."'")
```

Notice the back ticks, this needs to be used on the update, because it's a reserved word. You need to escape the reservation so you can use it as a column name.

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0):

`update` is a keyword in MySQL syntax, you shouldn't name a field `update`. Try naming it something like: `updated_at` or  `updated_date`

If you can't do this you must to quote the field name in your query:

```
"UPDATE Accounts 
SET likes='1',`update`='".$_."' 
WHERE username='".$_POST['username']."'"
```